# unable to determine what cmake generator to use

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, cmake

Whenever I try to build I get this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3CWX.png)

my setting looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayd9g.png)

any ideas? running vs code ofc

I tried to reset configuration via CMake:reset (something something)

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages **images** which represents *textual* information. Instead, copy paste error message and your settings directly to the question post as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Comment: As for "CMake generator", that notion is described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html). It is absolutely unrelated to the path to the `cmake` itself.

Comment: have you installed any buildystems for supported CMake generators to your system?